# change the background color depending on the prefix

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I want to change the background color depending on the prefix....the command I'm trying to use has given a syntax error, where am I going wrong? Or is this idea not possible

```
<body style="{!if(!$Site.Prefix == '/portalEllas',background: #164E4B,background: #0c4453)}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the output must be a string (enclosed in quotes). You also potentially have an extra `!`; the `!` in a merge formula is part of the merge syntax, as in `{!...}`. Anywhere else besides that, `!` acts as the `NOT()` function. Field names are not ordinarily prefixed with `!`. If you use it as written, it effectively makes the condition: `$Site.Prefix != '/portalEllas'`, which is probably not what you meant.

```
<body style="{!if($Site.Prefix == '/portalEllas','background: #164E4B','background: #0c4453')}">
```

You can optimize this by moving the background out of the formula:

```
<body style="background: {!if($Site.Prefix == '/portalEllas','#164E4B','#0c4453')}">
```

Comment: Thankyou !! Thanks for the help again @sfdcfox